# htacces not rewriting when file is in subdirectory

Tags: file, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess to rewrite some urls which works fine. But I recently moved some files in a directory to keep my file structure clean and now the rewrites stopped working.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Cross site access toestaan
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"

#CMS rewrite
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]

#Block ftpconfig
<FilesMatch ".ftpconfig">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteRule         ^home index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^verificatie/(.*)$ verify.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^login/(.*)$ account/login.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^login account/login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^uitloggen includes/uitloggen.php [QSA,L]
#Zorg ervoor dat onderstaande regels alleen worden uitgevoerd als het geen folder (d) is of een file (f)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ product.php?cat=$1&alias=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine: `RewriteRule           ^uitloggen includes/uitloggen.php [QSA,L]`.

But these rewrites give a 404 error when opening the page:

```
RewriteRule         ^login/(.*)$ account/login.php?alias=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule         ^login account/login.php [QSA,L]
```

This is my file structure:

```
root
- new
-- includes
-- account
```

My .htaccess file is in the `/new/` folder.

Why does one work but the other ones don't? I checked in my IDE and Filezilla if the files are really in those directories and I am 100% sure they are.

Comment: What URL in browser is causing 404 and what is working?

Comment: Maybe just a browser cache issue?